# My Jquery libraries won't reload when I navigate back to my page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Hello I am writing a MVC2 site that utilizes several Jquery Libraries to help improve some ui Elements.  One particular page updates a database and then navigates back to the original page and pulls the new data out of the database.  Now, for some reason, All of my jquery libraries simply won't reload with them causing a couple of very serious errors.  Fidler is telling me there is an HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized.  It happens to all of them.  I am not sure why this is?  What would cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this only happens on reload? That exception would point me towards a security problem with the files on disk. Maybe the web process has no permission to view them? Can you read the files correctly when you try to access them via their url directly?

Comment: That's what I though originally.  But I realized that all the files must load properly originally.  The errors that I get don't occur, until I attempt to reload the page.  Fidler says the files load just fine when I first open the page,  All though they load initially with the same error, they eventually all load up.  But on the redirect they do no such thing.  Could the redirect have something to do with that?

Comment: Are you sure the url's haven't changed on reload? Something with root dir perhaps?

Comment: I'll have to look a little closer, but I don't think so.  It seems like the files are being found, it's just that I can't access them due to some kind of security restriction.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a screenshot with the url's visible and the result of the http get? may be via fiddler, or firebug, or poster, or...

Comment: Visible URL's can't happen.  I work in the healthcare industry and that is a fast way to get fired.

Comment: I see, can you check the server log then? To see on what url the 401 is getting thrown, and verify that these are correct? I don't know what webserver you are running, but in normal cases, it does keep track of these things.

Comment: @DmainEvent let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3010/discussion-between-bram-vandenbussche-and-dmainevent)